# How to get top product by quantity with multiple group by

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I have raw data something like this:

| date | id | age | state | gender | transaction | product | product type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | a | 25 | johor | male | 12ab | apple | fruit | 12 |
| 1/1/2023 | b | 30 | melaka | female | 98jh | pen | stationery | 5 |

and so on.

I have grouped the data by using this query

```
select 
extract (year from date) as year_date,
extract (month from date) as month_date,
state,
gender,
case when age <= 25 then '25 & Below'
    when age between 26 and 30 then '26 - 30'
    when age between 31 and 35 then '31 - 35'
    when age between 36 and 40 then '36 - 40'
    when age > 40 then '>40' end as age_group
```

to look like this

| year | month | state | gender | age group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | johor | male | 25 & Below |
| 2023 | 1 | johor | female | 25 & Below |

However, i wanted to add 2 more columns for top product purchased by quantity for each row (group by year,month,state,gender,age,group) possibly look like this

| year | month | state | gender | age group | top product | product type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | johor | male | 25 & Below | apple | fruit |
| 2023 | 1 | johor | female | 25 & Below | pineapple | fruit |

Comment: 'I have grouped the data by using this query' - maybe, but there is quite a lot missing from the published code. (from,group by ...) Also representative sample date would help and extract only works on data datatypes the published format looks like string.

Comment: @P.Salmon from rawdata group by 1,2,3,4,5. I managed to get the output with 5 columns (year,month,state,gender,age group). The last part is what troubling me which to get the top product in terms of quantity sold for each row